# Java - Resource Deallocation of Inline Expressions

Tags: java, resources, allocation

Say I have the following function

```
public static void myfunc(String filename) {
    new FileInputStream(filename);
}
```

When I call that function, will there be resource leak because the FileInputStream is never released?

And future reference, is there a way I could verify that the resource hasn't been released after the function has been called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a resource leak. Most IDEs (such as Eclipse) will issue a warning indicating this. You should probably do something like along the lines of:

```
public static void myfunc(String filename) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream stream = null;
    try {
        stream = new FileInputStream(filename);
        ...
    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

Or, if you're using Java 7, you could use the [try-with-resource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) statement.

Comment: +1 A resource leak is not guaranteed as it has a finalise() method which closes it.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way I could manually detect/verify such a leak?  Either within Eclipse or using an external tool?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there will be a resource leak. A FileInputStream should always be closed.

When the GC runs, the `finalize()` method should be called and the stream will be closed at that time, but you shouldn't rely on that.

The way to check that there will be a resource leak is by reading the javadoc, which explains it. Basically, all the classes implementing the Closeable interface should be closed explicitely.

Comment: Is there any other way to determine the resource leak besides just reading the javadoc?  For example, is there any way to examine what will be garbage collected by using an external tool?

Answer (score -1):

You understand that this function doesn't do anything useful, right? It's not returning the FileInputStream to a caller or doing anything with it.

Typically you would ensure that your stream is closed with a try/finally block:

```
InputStream input = null ; 

try {
    input = new FileInputStream(name);

    [read and process input]

} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I do understand.  Just wrote it for examples sake.